# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present using Spring Security OAuth

Tags: java, spring, facebook, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to add facebook login to my Spring Boot app using the example https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2

I am using the extremely simple sample "click" (https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2/tree/master/click). When I run that sample, it all works. However, trying to do the same in my app results in the JavaScript problem (happens when I click the "logon" link):

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=123456789&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&response_type=code&state=fc9RzD. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I don't really understand why the example works and it does not in my code. As far as I understood, the facebook server would need to add this header, so if it does it for the tutorial example, it should do it for my application as well, right?

I am using the same client-id and client-secret as the example app so it cannot be a facebook setting I guess?

Comment: You can not load the FB login dialog via AJAX. It has to be loaded in the top window instance, so that users can verify the address bar content to make sure they are actually logging in to Facebook, and not some phishing site.

Comment: But both are using `$http.get()` from Angular and running on http://localhost:8080

Comment: The only resource loaded with `$http.get()` in the sample is `/user` (on localhost). If you watch carefully it probably redirects to Facebook and comes back with the same error you are seeing. But the top level browser window can redirect there fine (because the click is not handled by angular).